# Did the movie Alice in Wonderland(2010) use live-action?

Tags: alice-in-wonderland

I was wondering about the movie *Alice in Wonderland*. How did it use live-action even though it was purely an animation? If it was to be compared to *Transformers: Dark of the Moon* for example, it can be easily made out that it was live-action without animation. Can you tell me what were the live action scenes in *Alice in Wonderland*?

Comment: _"If it was to be compared to Transformers: Dark of the Moon for example, it can be easily made out that it was live-action without animation"_ Really? It was filmed on the moon? With real-life giant talking fighting robots?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're talking about the 2010 *[Alice in Wonderland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_in_Wonderland_(2010_film))* directed by Tim Burton, the film was shot completely with [chroma key compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_screen) (aka green screen), once Alice arrived in Underland. All the exaggerated body parts and scenery were all created with [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-generated_imagery) and the actors used what's called [Motion Capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_capture) (mo-cap) to help the CGI animators track their movements and make the animations seem like they were real.

Here's what the set of the movie actually looked like during filming:

[image: on-set photo]
[image: on-set photo]

Also, in the movie *Transformers: Dark of the Moon*, all of the Autobots and Deceptacons were animated. Any fight scene in that movie was a [digital composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_compositing) of real and fake imagery.